# What is the best way to create a Comma separated String from numbers in a short[] Array in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a `short[] Numbers`;

Now I want to convert the numbers in the array into a string with each array value separated by a comma. How do I do this in C#?

```
short[] Numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

I want this as a string `"1,2,3,4"` to store in the database.

PS: I checked many questions in SO for the same topic but did not get exact match. Hence I am asking this one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following

```
string result = String.Join(",", Numbers);
```

Note: this won't work in 3.5 or earlier because `String.Join` lacks the necessary overloads.  To use this API the code would need to change to

```
string result = String.Join(",", Numbers.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: I didn't DV but I don't think that compiles.  `Numbers` needs to be an array of strings.

Comment: @JayRiggs definitely compiles and runs :)  Don't forget there is an `object[]` overload on `String.Join`

Comment: @JaredPar I hope it will be resolved to use the one with `IEnumerable<T>`. Otherwise you'd get some unnecessary boxing/unboxing from `object[]`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yep you're right.  I'm asleep at the wheel tonight (can't convert `short[]` -> `object[]`).  The `IEnumerable<T>` overload is the one which is called

Comment: I think that this might not have compiled in .net 3.5. I know they added overloads in .net 4.0 to take more stuff, I believe to remember it required a `string[]` in 3.5 and can take a `params object[]` in 4.0, but my memory is hazy here :)

Comment: @MichaelStum you are correct, just checked the 3.5 sources, will udpate answer

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using LINQ -

```
string result = String.Join(",", Numbers.Select(p=>p.ToString()).ToArray());
```

EDIT -

```
string result = String.Join(",", Numbers);
```

As pointed out by [Jean Hominal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113158/jean-hominal) below, the `Select` and the `ToArray` can be removed due to the `String.Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)` overload.

Comment: You can lose both the `Select` and the `ToArray` due to the `String.Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)` overload.

Comment: @JeanHominal, true that, will make it the same as Jared Par's answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
String result = string.Join(",", Numbers);
```

Comment: Exact answer as JaredPar

Comment: @AmitJoki i was first on this

Comment: Ok, I'll remove my DV

Comment: It was my mistake mate. Welcome ;)

Comment: @Rex: Surprised to see that even tough you answered correct first, your answer is lying in the bottom.

Comment: @ckv it happens sometimes :P